# How to get two tables among each other?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that holds the columnnames of different datasets. E.g.

```
ID|Col1   |Col2   |Col3|
------------------------
23|Name   |City   |Age |
24|Answer1|Answer2|Name|
```

I have another table that holds data for each of the columns in the table above.

```
ID|Col1   |Col2   |Col3|
------------------------
23|Marc   |Paris  |45  |
23|Frank  |Berlin |14  |
23|Ole    |Oslo   |65  |
24|Yes    |Yes    |Alex|
24|No     |Yes    |Thea|
```

I am looking for a way to get a table with a `where = ID` with the first column holding the column names and then the data that belong to that column. E.g.

```
ID|Col1   |Col2   |Col3|
------------------------
23|Name   |City   |Age |
23|Marc   |Paris  |45  |
23|Frank  |Berlin |14  |
23|Ole    |Oslo   |65  |
```

I already tried different Joins but all I got was all data in one column not among each other. Could anyone help me here?

I am working with `SQL Server` so using the `TSQL` dialect but I guess the answer has not be specific to `TSQL` so I added the `SQL` flag as well.

Comment: At a first glance, it seems to me that the table holding the data should be split into two tables, one table holding name, city, and age attributes, the other table holding answer and name attributes. In this way, you could e.g. acccount for the fact, that the age should be a number and the name should be a string.

Comment: I, indeed have to do this in a further step but I have 39 columns in table 1 and 1,200,000 columns in table 2 so was looking for a way to just view the data before solving the problem you mentioned in SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, 1 as [sort]
from table1 
where id = 23 
union all 
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, 2 
from table2
where id = 23  
order by sort
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL with `ID = 23` gives you the expected result:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   COLUMN_NAMES
WHERE  ID = 23
UNION
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM   DATA
WHERE  ID = 23
```